# How to clear part of the back buffer using pd3dDevice->Clear?

Tags: c++, direct3d, rect

I want to clear part of the back buffer using `pd3dDevice->Clear`

instead of using:

```
pd3dDevice->Clear(0, NULL ...
```

I want to clear a section using:

```
pd3dDevice->Clear(1, &rectB`
```

I have tried:

```
pd3dDevice->Clear(1, &rctB, D3DCLEAR_TARGET, D3DCOLOR_XRGB(r, g, b), 1.0f, 0);
```

with `RECT rctB = { 20, 30, 180, 230 };`

I'm getting compile errors, The `(r, g, b)` part of the statement are parameters passed into `void Part_Cls(int r, int g, int b)`

The compile error is:

> 2 IntelliSense: argument of type "RECT *" is incompatible with parameter of type "const D3DRECT *"    c:\Source\example\example\winmain.cpp   199 23  example

Comment: Make rctB a D3DRECT instead?

Comment: Your suggestion of making rectB a D3DRECT has worked, thank you.